# Stored procedure cast error

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a strange problem with the following SP:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Manufacturer_GetProductsCountByManufacturedId]
(
    @ManufacturerIds NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @ExcludeType INT
)
AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @ManufacturerId NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @GoodManufacturerIds NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @result BIGINT  
    DECLARE @pos INT
    DECLARE @len INT

    SET @GoodManufacturerIds = ''
    SET @pos = 0
    SET @len = 0

    WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @ManufacturerIds, @pos + 1)>0
    BEGIN
        -- Split
        SET @len = CHARINDEX(',', @ManufacturerIds, @pos+1) - @pos
        SET @ManufacturerId = SUBSTRING(@ManufacturerIds, @pos, @len)

        -- Check
        SELECT TOP 1 @result = p.ProductId
        FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[Product] p
        INNER JOIN [MYDB].[ProductTyping].[TypedProductFieldValue] tpfv ON tpfv.ProductId = p.ProductId
        WHERE ManufacturerId = @ManufacturerId 
        AND tpfv.ProductTypeId <> @ExcludeType    

        IF @result > 0
            SET @GoodManufacturerIds = @GoodManufacturerIds + @ManufacturerId + ','
        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @ManufacturerIds, @pos+@len)+1
    END
    -- Last comma kaputt
    SET @GoodManufacturerIds = LEFT(@GoodManufacturerIds, LEN(@GoodManufacturerIds) - 1)

    RETURN @GoodManufacturerIds
END
```

Basically I have to split a string with comma-separated values and for each on those values, I execute a query and put the result in another comma-separated string.
If I send these values as stored procedure parameters, (**"5220,3008,1561,2678,"** and **5**) I got an error, *"Unable to cast nvarchar values '5220,3008,1561,2678' to type int"*.
BUT If I built in those values in the stored procedure as:

```sql
    DECLARE @ManufacturerId NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @GoodManufacturerIds NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @result BIGINT  
    DECLARE @pos INT
    DECLARE @len INT

    -- test
    DECLARE @ManufacturerIds NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @ExcludeType INT    
    SET @ManufacturerIds = '5220,3008,1561,2678,13715,5047,'
    SET @ExcludeType = 5

    SET @GoodManufacturerIds = ''
    SET @pos = 0
    SET @len = 0

    WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @ManufacturerIds, @pos + 1)>0
    BEGIN
        -- Split
        SET @len = CHARINDEX(',', @ManufacturerIds, @pos+1) - @pos
        SET @ManufacturerId = SUBSTRING(@ManufacturerIds, @pos, @len)

        -- Check
        SELECT TOP 1 @result = p.ProductId
        FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[Product] p
        INNER JOIN [MYDB].[ProductTyping].[TypedProductFieldValue] tpfv ON tpfv.ProductId = p.ProductId
        WHERE ManufacturerId = @ManufacturerId 
        AND tpfv.ProductTypeId <> @ExcludeType    

        IF @result > 0
            SET @GoodManufacturerIds = @GoodManufacturerIds + @ManufacturerId + ','
        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @ManufacturerIds, @pos+@len)+1
    END
    -- Last comma kaputt
    SET @GoodManufacturerIds = LEFT(@GoodManufacturerIds, LEN(@GoodManufacturerIds) - 1)

    RETURN @GoodManufacturerIds
```

Everything works fine and I got my new string. 
I dunno where the error could be in the first procedure, any hints?

Comment: Why not use a data type *designed* to hold multiple values, such as XML or a table, rather than stuffing everything into strings?

Comment: Hi  t-clausen.dk, I've update the post using the correct syntax highlight, now you can see the "<>"

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, I was using RETURN but RETURN is for integer values and in this case mine is a string, so putting SELECT make everything works fine.